# How to get access to the job host id

Tags: azure-functions

I see that when my functions app starts, it logs the job host id (and when deployed in azure, the is the name of the function app that the solution is deployed to).  I want to access this value in order to integrate it into our enterprise logging solutions, but am having difficulty finding how this can be done.  I am aware of ExecutionContext, and have pulled some values from there, but unfortunately there is nothing there like job host id.

Comment: For a bit more context, I'm wanting to retrieve the JobHost id, and set a property in the Log4Net.GlobalContext so that the Gelf4Net appender will tag log entries in graylog with it.

Comment: This is not a supported scenario right now. In theory, the value could be dded to the ExecutionContext. Could you kindly open a new GitHub issue at https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/new to track this request?

Comment: Sure - thanks  @LingToh